# Not showing downloaded images in sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-image

im loading 10 images from web to sd card , my code created sub folder in sd card and load all 10 images but only 1st time after that time it does not load and store any image , also there is no error in logcat. here is my code :

```
reviewImageLink = u_image;
                 URL reviewImageURL;
                String name = reviewImageLink.substring(reviewImageLink.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    try {
                        reviewImageURL = new URL(reviewImageLink);
                        if (!hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(name)) {
                            isImage = false;
                            new DownloadImageTask().execute(reviewImageURL);
                            Log.v("log_tag", "if");
                            isImage = true;
                            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources().getString(R.string.directory));
                            sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
                            file = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, name);
                            Log.v("log_tag", "Directory created");
                        }

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
```

DownloadImageTask:

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Bitmap> {
    // This class definition states that DownloadImageTask will take String
    // parameters, publish Integer progress updates, and return a Bitmap
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... paths) {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = paths[0];
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int length = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
            byte[] imageData = new byte[length];
            int buffersize = (int) Math.ceil(length / (double) 100);
            int downloaded = 0;
            int read;
            while (downloaded < length) {
                if (length < buffersize) {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length);
                } else if ((length - downloaded) <= buffersize) {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length
                            - downloaded);
                } else {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, buffersize);
                }
                downloaded += read;
                publishProgress((downloaded * 100) / length);
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                    length);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap created");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap not created");
            }
            is.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Malformed exception: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        String name = reviewImageLink.substring(reviewImageLink
                .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        if (result != null) {
            hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(name);
            saveToSDCard(result, name);
            isImage = true;

        } else {
            isImage = false;

        }
    }
}

public void saveToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        Log.v(TAG, "SD Card is available for read and write "+ mExternalStorageAvailable + mExternalStorageWriteable);
        saveFile(bitmap, name);
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        Log.v(TAG, "SD Card is available for read "+ mExternalStorageAvailable);
    } else {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        Log.v(TAG, "Please insert a SD Card to save your Video "+ mExternalStorageAvailable + mExternalStorageWriteable);
    }
}

private void saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String name) 
{
    String filename = name;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources().getString(R.string.directory));
    sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
    File outputFile = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outputFile.toString());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "output.png");
    Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);

    try 
    {
        OutputStream outStream = this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(String name) {
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources().getString(R.string.directory));
    File file = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, name);
    if (file != null) 
    {
        file.delete();
    }
    return file.exists();
}
```

here is logcat :

```
02-20 08:49:46.999: D/dalvikvm(346): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5254 objects / 245320 bytes in 69ms
02-20 08:50:00.138: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:00.148: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
02-20 08:50:03.628: D/dalvikvm(346): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4548 objects / 238192 bytes in 68ms
02-20 08:50:03.728: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:03.738: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
02-20 08:50:04.898: D/dalvikvm(346): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 585 objects / 85272 bytes in 107ms
02-20 08:50:05.018: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:05.049: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
02-20 08:50:05.528: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:06.409: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
02-20 08:50:10.968: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:10.968: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
02-20 08:50:12.368: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:12.380: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
02-20 08:50:15.569: D/dalvikvm(346): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4584 objects / 358728 bytes in 58ms
02-20 08:50:15.619: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:15.629: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
02-20 08:50:22.179: I/Topten(346): Bitmap created
02-20 08:50:22.189: V/Topten(346): SD Card is available for read and write truetrue
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Your code seem to be correct..I haven't found anything wrong in it.
I am not sure Whether it is the reason or not but..
Before creating directory  check whether directory exist or not

```
if(!sdImageMainDirectory.exists()){
sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
}
```

Check once and getback to me...to analyze further...I hope this will help you.

---

You haven't write files to the external storage you just created a file...Try to Write file into the external storage and make sure that you've set the permission External Storage write

Comment: @BibiTahira it won't effect the files..Instead it stop creating directory each everytime(i.e only one folder). I have also found something wrong  String name = reviewImageLink.substring(reviewImageLink
                .lastIndexOf("/") + 1); substring with single parameter or is it a copy paste problem...?

Comment: Substring should have two parameter...I suspect you are getting the same file name each and every time that's why I have looked at that.it should be. String name = reviewImageLink.substring(reviewImageLink .lastIndexOf("/") + 1,reviewImageLink.length());

Comment: Exception:  **02-20 23:49:03.552: E/Topten(1912): IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: img51.imageporter.com:80
02-20 23:49:03.561: E/Topten(1912): IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: img51.imageporter.com:80
02-20 23:49:03.561: E/Topten(1912): IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: img51.imageporter.com:80
02-20 23:49:03.572: E/Topten(1912): IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: img51.imageporter.com:80**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24878/discussion-between-pragnani-and-bibi-tahira)

Answer (score 0):

If I was not wrong, your variable **reviewImageLink** is a class variable. Then, in your DownloadImageTask, you are using **reviewImageLink** to generate the file name and save your image in this file.

The problem is: if you calling your function 10 times, one by one, your class variable **reviewImageLink** will be overwrited by the last calling. This may cause your app to save only one images all the time.

My suggestion is you can generate your image file name inside your DownloadImageTask. So after downloading completes, it will save the image files in seperate files.

Here is how I download images and save in local. I put downloading and saving in AsyncTask class. I also decide the file name inside AsyncTask. So there is no conflicate between other downloading process. Please check my **DownloadImageTask** class.

http://jmsliu.com/1929/android-progress-dialog-example.html